# Disabled dedicated GPU powers on after suspend (and also just randomly)

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia, graphics, power-management, hybrid-graphics

I have a laptop with integrated AMD graphics and discrete Nvidia GTX 1650Ti.

```
$ sudo lspci
...
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Ti Mobile] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10fa (rev a1)
...
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir (rev c7)
```

Distro: Ubuntu 21.04

Kernel: 5.11.0-17-generic

I use

```
$ sudo prime-select intel
```

to disable Nvidia Graphics and also set PCI power management to auto using TLP:

```
$ sudo tlp-stat
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/power/control = auto (0x030000, VGA compatible controller, no driver)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.1/power/control = auto (0x040300, Audio device, snd_hda_intel)
```

This works great, the GPU is in low power mode and battery life is good:

```
$ cat /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/power_state
D3cold
```

But after I use suspend the GPU starts to consume more power again:

```
$ cat /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/power_state
D0
```

This also happens randomly during laptop being on sometimes.

Please help. This thing halves my laptop's battery life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [system76-power](https://github.com/pop-os/system76-power) Works well.

Also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1341945/disabled-dedicated-gpu-powers-on-after-suspend